# Convert awesomium screenshot to Stream

Tags: .net, awesomium

Here is how I make awesomium screenshot:

```
webView2.Render().SaveToPng("filePath");
```

The problem is that I now need not to save bytes to file but get them inmemory. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states that [Render() returns an instance of RenderBuffer](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_2/sharp_api/html/7f9fbbb0-ecfc-eab5-f75c-6da546af99e0.htm), which has a property called [Buffer](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_2/sharp_api/html/cb3d39b3-f846-f51a-5ea0-5a8018a9819a.htm), that returns the raw pixel data (as an [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx)). 
If you still need a byte array, you could use [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) to copy the data into a byte array. This way, you can do it without the need of a temporary file.

Comment: I am not sure how to get the length of destination byte array

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can determine the size in bytes of the destination buffer by multiplying RenderBuffer.Rowspan by RenderBuffer.Height.

Answer (score 2):

The API doesn't seem to provide an overload that takes a stream, but you can always save to a temporary file and load the file into a `MemoryStream`:

```
string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
webView2.Render().SaveToPng(fileName);
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
File.Delete(fileName);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```